# After form submission,reloading page in codeigniter4 application, redirects to the page omitting the public in url giving 404. How to prevent this?

Tags: php, codeigniter, page-refresh, codeigniter-4

I developed a codeigniter4 application. The sign-in page I created is coded to redirect to itself after page submission using:

```
return $this->response->redirect(base_url('public/index.php/auth'));
```

The page redirects but after form submission, When I do a page reload, the browser asks for a confirm form resubmussion and on clicking continue, the page directs to `<PROJECTROOT>/index.php/auth` instead of `<PROJECTROOT>/public/index.php/auth` giving a 404 file not found error.

How does the public gets omitted here. How can I get the page reloaded correctly?

##### AuthController.php

```php
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;
use Config\Services;
use App\Models\UserModel;

class Auth extends BaseController {


    // login
    public function index()
    {
       
        helper(['form']);
        
        $session = session();
      
        $email = $session->get('email');

       if ($email) {
       
           $password = $session->get('password');
           $this->chooseLoginTo($email,$password,$session);

       }
       else if($this->request->getVar('email')){
        
         $this->processLogin();
       }
       else {
         $this->_showLoginForm();
       }
    }
    
    public function processLogin()
    {
      helper(['form']);
      //set rules validation form
      $rules = [
          'email'         => 'required|min_length[6]|max_length[50]|valid_email',
          'password'      => 'required|min_length[6]|max_length[200]'
      ];

      if($this->validate($rules)){
        $this->_login();

      }
        else {
          $this->_showLoginForm();
        }
    }


    private function _showLoginForm()
    {
      $data['title'] = 'e-Ticketing Incident Reporting & Feedback IMS';
      $data['validation'] = $this->validator;

      //echo view('auth/login', $data);
        echo view('sign-in',$data);
    }

    /*public function xss_clean($data){
      $newdata=[];
      foreach($data as $key=>$value){
        $value = htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8');
        $newdata[$key]=$value;
      }
      return $newdata;
    }*/

    private function _login()
    {

        $session=session();
        $request = service('request');
        $email =$request->getVar('email');
        $password=$request->getVar('password');

        $this->chooseLoginTo($email,$password,$session);

    }

    public function chooseLoginTo($email,$password,$session){
        helper('my_helper');
      $model = new \App\Models\UserModel();
      $user = $model->where('email', $email)->first();
        //print_r($user);exit();
      if ($user) {
          if ($user['is_active'] == 1) {

              if (password_verify($password, $user['password'])) {

                  $data = [
                      'name' => $user['name'],
                      'email' => $user['email'],
                      'role_id' => $user['role_id'],
                      'logged_in' => TRUE
                  ];
                  
                  $data=xss_clean($data);
                 
                  $session->set($data);
                  if ($user['role_id'] == 1) {
                   
                      return $this->response->redirect(base_url('public/index.php/admin') );
                  } elseif($user['role_id'] == 3) {
                    return $this->response->redirect(base_url('public/index.php/report') );

                  
                  }
                  else{
                   
                    return $this->response->redirect(base_url('public/index.php/dashboard'));

                    
                  }
              }else{

                  $session->setFlashdata('msg', '<div class="bg-red-100 rounded-lg py-5 px-6 mb-4 text-base text-red-700 mb-3 error" role="alert">

                  Wrong Password!</div>');
                  return $this->response->redirect(base_url('public/index.php/auth') );
                }
          } else {
                $session->setFlashdata('msg', '<div class="error alert-danger" role="alert">
              This email has not been activated yet!</div>');
              
              return $this->response->redirect(base_url('public/index.php/auth') );
            }
      } else {
            $session->setFlashdata('msg', '<div class="error alert-danger" role="alert">
          Email is not registered!</div>');
          
          return $this->response->redirect(base_url('public/index.php/auth') );
        }
    }
}
```

##### View: sign-in.php

```html
<!--
=========================================================
* Soft UI Dashboard Tailwind - v1.0.4
=========================================================

* Product Page: https://www.creative-tim.com/product/soft-ui-dashboard-tailwind
* Copyright 2022 Creative Tim (https://www.creative-tim.com)
* Licensed under MIT (https://www.creative-tim.com/license)
* Coded by Creative Tim

=========================================================

* The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="../assets/img/apple-icon.png" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../assets/img/favicon.png" />
    <title><?=$title?></title>
    <!-- Fonts and icons -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Font Awesome Icons -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/42d5adcbca.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   
    <!-- Nucleo Icons -->
    <link href="../assets/css/nucleo-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../assets/css/nucleo-svg.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    <!-- Main Styling -->

    <link href="../assets/css/soft-ui-dashboard-tailwind.css?v=1.0.4" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    .errors {font-size:small;color:red;}
    .error {font-size:small;color:red;}
    .alert {font-size:small;color:red;}
    </style>
 
  </head>

  <body class="m-0 font-sans antialiased font-normal bg-white text-start text-base leading-default text-slate-500">
    <div class="container sticky top-0 z-sticky">
      <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3">
        <div class="w-full max-w-full px-3 flex-0">
          <!-- Navbar -->
          <nav class="absolute top-0 left-0 right-0 z-30 flex flex-wrap items-center px-4 py-2 mx-6 my-4 shadow-soft-2xl rounded-blur bg-white/80 backdrop-blur-2xl backdrop-saturate-200 lg:flex-nowrap lg:justify-start">
            <div class="flex items-center justify-between w-full p-0 pl-6 mx-auto flex-wrap-inherit">
              <!--<a class="py-2.375 text-xl mr-4 ml-4 whitespace-nowrap font-bold text-slate-700 lg:ml-0 animate__animated animate__heartBeat" href=""> <?=$title ?> </a>
              -->
              <h3 class="h4 text-gray-900 mb-4 "><?= $title; ?></h1>

              <button navbar-trigger class="px-3 py-1 ml-2 leading-none transition-all bg-transparent border border-transparent border-solid rounded-lg shadow-none cursor-pointer text-lg ease-soft-in-out lg:hidden" type="button" aria-controls="navigation" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="inline-block mt-2 align-middle bg-center bg-no-repeat bg-cover w-6 h-6 bg-none">
                  <span bar1 class="w-5.5 rounded-xs relative my-0 mx-auto block h-px bg-gray-600 transition-all duration-300"></span>
                  <span bar2 class="w-5.5 rounded-xs mt-1.75 relative my-0 mx-auto block h-px bg-gray-600 transition-all duration-300"></span>
                  <span bar3 class="w-5.5 rounded-xs mt-1.75 relative my-0 mx-auto block h-px bg-gray-600 transition-all duration-300"></span>
                </span>
              </button>
              <div navbar-menu class="items-center flex-grow overflow-hidden transition-all duration-500 ease-soft lg-max:max-h-0 basis-full lg:flex lg:basis-auto">
                <ul class="flex flex-col pl-0 mx-auto mb-0 list-none lg:flex-row xl:ml-auto">
                  <!--<li>
                    <a class="flex items-center px-4 py-2 mr-2 font-normal transition-all lg-max:opacity-0 duration-250 ease-soft-in-out text-sm text-slate-700 lg:px-2" aria-current="page" href="../pages/dashboard.html">
                      <i class="mr-1 fa fa-chart-pie opacity-60"></i>
                      Dashboard
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a class="block px-4 py-2 mr-2 font-normal transition-all lg-max:opacity-0 duration-250 ease-soft-in-out text-sm text-slate-700 lg:px-2" href="../pages/profile.html">
                      <i class="mr-1 fa fa-user opacity-60"></i>
                      Profile
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a class="block px-4 py-2 mr-2 font-normal transition-all lg-max:opacity-0 duration-250 ease-soft-in-out text-sm text-slate-700 lg:px-2" href="../pages/sign-up.html">
                      <i class="mr-1 fas fa-user-circle opacity-60"></i>
                      Sign Up
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a class="block px-4 py-2 mr-2 font-normal transition-all lg-max:opacity-0 duration-250 ease-soft-in-out text-sm text-slate-700 lg:px-2" href="../pages/sign-in.html">
                      <i class="mr-1 fas fa-key opacity-60"></i>
                      Sign In
                    </a>
                  </li>-->
                </ul> 
                <!-- online builder btn  -->
                 <!--<li class="flex items-center">
                  <a
                    class="leading-pro ease-soft-in text-fuchsia-500 border-fuchsia-500 text-xs tracking-tight-soft bg-150 bg-x-25 rounded-3.5xl hover:border-fuchsia-500 hover:scale-102 hover:text-fuchsia-500 active:hover:border-fuchsia-500 active:hover:scale-102 active:hover:text-fuchsia-500 active:opacity-85 active:shadow-soft-xs active:bg-fuchsia-500 active:border-fuchsia-500 mr-2 mb-0 inline-block cursor-pointer border border-solid bg-transparent py-2 px-8 text-center align-middle font-bold uppercase shadow-none transition-all hover:bg-transparent hover:opacity-75 hover:shadow-none active:scale-100 active:text-white active:hover:bg-transparent active:hover:opacity-75 active:hover:shadow-none"
                    target="_blank"
                    href="https://www.creative-tim.com/builder/soft-ui?ref=navbar-dashboard&amp;_ga=2.76518741.1192788655.1647724933-1242940210.1644448053"
                    >Online Builder</a
                  >
                </li> -->
                <ul class="hidden pl-0 mb-0 list-none lg:block lg:flex-row">
                  <li>
                    <a href="<?= base_url('public/index.php/auth/registration')?>" target="_blank" class="leading-pro hover:scale-102 hover:shadow-soft-xs active:opacity-85 ease-soft-in text-xs tracking-tight-soft shadow-soft-md bg-150 bg-x-25 bg-gradient-to-tl from-gray-900 to-slate-800 rounded-3.5xl mb-0 mr-1 inline-block cursor-pointer border-0 bg-transparent px-8 py-2 text-center align-middle font-bold uppercase text-white transition-all">Client Registration</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div> 
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
                                
    <?=form_open(base_url('public/index.php/auth'));
     ?>
    <main class="mt-0 transition-all duration-200 ease-soft-in-out">
      <section>

        <div class="relative flex items-center p-0 overflow-hidden bg-center bg-cover min-h-75-screen">
          <div class="container z-10">
            <div class="flex flex-wrap mt-0 -mx-3">
              <div class="flex flex-col w-full max-w-full px-3 mx-auto md:flex-0 shrink-0 md:w-6/12 lg:w-5/12 xl:w-4/12">
                <div class="relative flex flex-col min-w-0 mt-32 break-words bg-transparent border-0 shadow-none rounded-2xl bg-clip-border">
                  <div class="p-6 pb-0 mb-0 bg-transparent border-b-0 rounded-t-2xl">
                    <h3 class="relative z-10 font-bold text-transparent bg-gradient-to-tl from-blue-600 to-cyan-400 bg-clip-text">Sign In Page</h3>
                    <p class="mb-0">Enter your email and password to sign in</p>
                  </div>
                  <!--<div class="bg-red-100 rounded-lg py-5 px-6 mb-4 text-base text-red-700 mb-3 error" role="alert">
                  -->
                  <?= \Config\Services::validation()->listErrors(); ?>
                 <!-- </div> -->
                  
                                <span class="d-none alert alert-success mb-3" id="res_message"></span>
                                <!--<div class="bg-red-100 rounded-lg py-5 px-6 mb-4 text-base text-red-700 mb-3" role="alert">
-->
                                <?php if(session()->getFlashdata('msg')):?>
                                  <?= session()->getFlashdata('msg') ?>
                                  
                                <?php endif;
                                 unset($_SESSION['msg']);
                                ?>
                                <!--</div>-->
                  <div class="flex-auto p-6">
                    <form role="form">
                      <label class="mb-2 ml-1 font-bold text-xs text-slate-700">Email</label>
                      <div class="mb-4">
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="focus:shadow-soft-primary-outline text-sm leading-5.6 ease-soft block w-full appearance-none rounded-lg border border-solid border-gray-300 bg-white bg-clip-padding px-3 py-2 font-normal text-gray-700 transition-all focus:border-fuchsia-300 focus:outline-none focus:transition-shadow" placeholder="Email" aria-label="Email" aria-describedby="email-addon" />
                      </div>
                      <label class="mb-2 ml-1 font-bold text-xs text-slate-700">Password</label>
                      <div class="mb-4">
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="focus:shadow-soft-primary-outline text-sm leading-5.6 ease-soft block w-full appearance-none rounded-lg border border-solid border-gray-300 bg-white bg-clip-padding px-3 py-2 font-normal text-gray-700 transition-all focus:border-fuchsia-300 focus:outline-none focus:transition-shadow" placeholder="Password" aria-label="Password" aria-describedby="password-addon" />
                      </div>
                      <!--<div class="min-h-6 mb-0.5 block pl-12">
                        <input id="rememberMe" class="mt-0.54 rounded-10 duration-250 ease-soft-in-out after:rounded-circle after:shadow-soft-2xl after:duration-250 checked:after:translate-x-5.25 h-5 relative float-left -ml-12 w-10 cursor-pointer appearance-none border border-solid border-gray-200 bg-slate-800/10 bg-none bg-contain bg-left bg-no-repeat align-top transition-all after:absolute after:top-px after:h-4 after:w-4 after:translate-x-px after:bg-white after:content-[''] checked:border-slate-800/95 checked:bg-slate-800/95 checked:bg-none checked:bg-right" type="checkbox" checked="" />
                        <label class="mb-2 ml-1 font-normal cursor-pointer select-none text-sm text-slate-700" for="rememberMe">Remember me</label>
                      </div>-->
                      <div class="text-center">
                        <!--<button type="submit" class="inline-block w-full px-6 py-3 mt-6 mb-0 font-bold text-center text-white uppercase align-middle transition-all bg-transparent border-0 rounded-lg cursor-pointer shadow-soft-md bg-x-25 bg-150 leading-pro text-xs ease-soft-in tracking-tight-soft bg-gradient-to-tl from-blue-600 to-cyan-400 hover:scale-102 hover:shadow-soft-xs active:opacity-85">Sign in</button>-->
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign In" class="inline-block w-full px-6 py-3 mt-6 mb-0 font-bold text-center text-white uppercase align-middle transition-all bg-transparent border-0 rounded-lg cursor-pointer shadow-soft-md bg-x-25 bg-150 leading-pro text-xs ease-soft-in tracking-tight-soft bg-gradient-to-tl from-blue-600 to-cyan-400 hover:scale-102 hover:shadow-soft-xs active:opacity-85" />  
                      </div>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                  <!--
                  <div class="p-6 px-1 pt-0 text-center bg-transparent border-t-0 border-t-solid rounded-b-2xl lg:px-2">
                    <p class="mx-auto mb-6 leading-normal text-sm">
                      Don't have an account?
                      <a href="../pages/sign-up.html" class="relative z-10 font-semibold text-transparent bg-gradient-to-tl from-blue-600 to-cyan-400 bg-clip-text">Sign up</a>
                    </p>
                  </div> -->
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="w-full max-w-full px-3 lg:flex-0 shrink-0 md:w-6/12">
                <div class="absolute top-0 hidden w-3/5 h-full -mr-32 overflow-hidden -skew-x-10 -right-40 rounded-bl-xl md:block">
                  <div class="absolute inset-x-0 top-0 z-0 h-full -ml-16 bg-cover skew-x-10" style="background-image: url('<?=base_url('public')?>/assets/img/curved-images/curved6.jpg')"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
    <footer class="py-12">
      <div class="container">
        <!--<div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3">
          <div class="flex-shrink-0 w-full max-w-full mx-auto mb-6 text-center lg:flex-0 lg:w-8/12">
            <a href="javascript:;" target="_blank" class="mb-2 mr-4 text-slate-400 sm:mb-0 xl:mr-12"> Company </a>
            <a href="javascript:;" target="_blank" class="mb-2 mr-4 text-slate-400 sm:mb-0 xl:mr-12"> About Us </a>
            <a href="javascript:;" target="_blank" class="mb-2 mr-4 text-slate-400 sm:mb-0 xl:mr-12"> Team </a>
            <a href="javascript:;" target="_blank" class="mb-2 mr-4 text-slate-400 sm:mb-0 xl:mr-12"> Products </a>
            <a href="javascript:;" target="_blank" class="mb-2 mr-4 text-slate-400 sm:mb-0 xl:mr-12"> Blog </a>
            <a href="javascript:;" target="_blank" class="mb-2 mr-4 text-slate-400 sm:mb-0 xl:mr-12"> Pricing </a>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-shrink-0 w-full max-w-full mx-auto mt-2 mb-6 text-center lg:flex-0 lg:w-8/12">
            <a href="javascript:;" target="_blank" class="mr-6 text-slate-400">
              <span class="text-lg fab fa-dribbble"></span>
            </a>
            <a href="javascript:;" target="_blank" class="mr-6 text-slate-400">
              <span class="text-lg fab fa-twitter"></span>
            </a>
            <a href="javascript:;" target="_blank" class="mr-6 text-slate-400">
              <span class="text-lg fab fa-instagram"></span>
            </a>
            <a href="javascript:;" target="_blank" class="mr-6 text-slate-400">
              <span class="text-lg fab fa-pinterest"></span>
            </a>
            <a href="javascript:;" target="_blank" class="mr-6 text-slate-400">
              <span class="text-lg fab fa-github"></span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div> -->
        <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3">
          <div class="w-8/12 max-w-full px-3 mx-auto mt-1 text-center flex-0">
            <p class="mb-0 text-slate-400">
              Copyright ©
              <script>
                document.write(new Date().getFullYear());
              </script>
              <?=$title;?> C-DIT
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </body>
  <script>
if ($("#login").length > 0) {
$("#login").validate({
rules: {
password: {
required: true,
},
email: {
required: true,
maxlength: 50,
email: true,
},
},
messages: {
password: {
required: "Please enter password",
},
email: {
required: "Please enter valid email",
email: "Please enter valid email",
maxlength: "The email name should less than or equal to 50 characters",
},
},
})
}
</script> 
  <!-- plugin for scrollbar  -->
  <script src="../assets/js/plugins/perfect-scrollbar.min.js" async></script>
  <!-- main script file  -->
  <script src="../assets/js/soft-ui-dashboard-tailwind.js?v=1.0.4" async></script>
</html>
```

##### .htaccess

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

##### Routes.php

*(app/Config/Routes.php)*

```php
$routes->get('/auth', 'Auth::index');
$routes->post('/auth', 'Auth::index');
```

Comment: What is a "page reload"?  Is that a Page Refresh? I know nothing about codeigniter, but when I need to do a redirect, I use header(Location:  $url).  Works every time and the Browser does not complain.

Answer (score 1):

*(AuthController.php)*

Instead of:❌

```php
return $this->response->redirect(base_url('public/index.php/auth'));
```

Use this:✅

```php
return redirect()->back()->withInput();
```

##### Resources:

[`old($key[, $default = null[, $escape = 'html']])`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/common_functions.html?highlight=redirect#old)

[`redirect(string $route)`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/common_functions.html?highlight=redirect#redirect)

##### Addendum 1

Make sure your `public/.htaccess` file is **similar** to:

[CodeIgniter4/`public/.htaccess`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/8d6584d95567eb7f5c1af86404525079321f97f0/public/.htaccess#L34)

##### Addendum 2

*(View: sign-in.php)*

Replace:

```php
 <?=form_open(base_url('public/index.php/auth'));
     ?>
```

With:

```php
<?= echo form_open('/auth'); ?>
```

Your HTML markup is quite messed up. You have a [`form_open(...)`](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#form_open) without a corresponding [`form_close(...)`](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#form_close) declaration.

In addition, you seem to have **nested** `<form>` tags, which doesn't make sense. You can't nest `<form>` tags.
[Can you nest HTML forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms)

Your inner `<form>` tag also lucks an `action="..."` attribute.

##### Addendum 3

In your Controller, you seem to have a lot of `Redirect` routes in the form of: `return $this->response->redirect(base_url('public/index.php/...')`. Set up explicit *user-defined routes* in `app/Config/Routes.php` if you haven't done so already. In addition, in your Controller, replace **all** the `Redirect` routes with something similar to: `return redirect()->to('/admin');`

##### Addendum 4

*(app/Config/Routes.php)*

Ensure that auto-routing is disabled. I.e:

```
$routes->setAutoRoute(false);
```

Comment: This doesnt solve my problem. Please see my controller and view files mentioned in comment.

Comment: @Tanzeem Please take a look at the *Addendum* section of my edited answer. Based on the availed information, it appears that you immensely modified the default `public/.htaccess` file. Was that intentional?

Comment: I copied the new .htaccess. But the problem still persisists

Comment: @Tanzeem Check my edited answer once again.

Comment: The problem got fixed with your suggesstions. I had also to change the baseurl in **Config/App.php** to : **public $baseURL = 'http://192.168.2.160/demo/public';**

Comment: I got a new problem. Now the redirection doesnt work. The `return redirect()->to('/admin');` doesnt redirect to the view page specified in the index of Admin controller. It redirects to a blank page with the url `http://192.168.2.160/demo/public/index.php/auth`

Comment: I changed `return redirect()->to('/admin');` to `$this->response->redirect(site_url('/admin'));` and it works

Comment: Also `return redirect()->back()->withInput();` doesnt works. This also redirects to a blank page with url `http://192.168.2.160/demo/public/index.php/auth`.